# how to delete guilty jar file after grails dependency-report

Tags: grails, jboss

when I tried to run `grails -Dgrails.env=local run-app`, I got the below error

> Server failed to start: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of ) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/management/MBeanServer"

After analysing I understood that it has something to do with "Two dependencies link the same jar with different versions"

I ran `grails dependency-report`, and here is the observation:

> commons-beanutils by commons-beanutils    1.8.3   release default false       227 kB
>   commons-beanutils by commons-beanutils  1.8.0   release default true        0 kB(evicted by 1.8.3)

How do I exclude this jar or remove the linkage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency report should show what is pulling in the problematic jar.  Once you have that,  explicitly exclude it from the dependencies in your BuildConfig.groovy, like so:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    dependencies {
        runtime("i-depend-on-beanutils-1.8.3") {
            excludes "beanutils"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the dependency-report output : org.apache.shiro shiro-core 1.1.0 default, compile, runtime, master 1.8.3
org.grails.internal wizard 0.1 default, compile 1.8.0

Comment: so how do i include 1.8.3 here as runtime ('org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.8.3') {
            excludes('commons-beanutils')
         }, its not working

Comment: It should be 1.1.0 for the shiro version number, like `runtime ('org.apache.shiro:shiro-core:1.1.0') { excludes('commons-beanutils') }`

Comment: still no luck :-( , to confirm what i have included here, its organization, name and revision in runtime and in excludes i have included artifact

Comment: Ok, I think if the dependency is included by a plugin, you have to configure the it in `plugins` rather than `dependencies`.  Try replacing the enclosing `dependencies` closure with `plugins`, like grails.project.dependency.resolution = { plugins { runtime(...`

Comment: thanks for the quick responses...but still no luck...it says failed downloads...after including it in plugins

Comment: hi, any idea why I am getting the failed downloads error(failed to resolve plugins), any input would be useful

Comment: may be i will keep exploring on this one and will try to run the jboss from local separately :-)